# Shutdown without Notepad++ asking me to save open files

Tags: notepad++

It used to be that I could just shut down (Windows) without Notepad++ bothering me. And when I turned my computer on again, Notepad++ could just open with all the same files as before.

But after the latest update from Notepad++ (late Nov 2022), whenever I shut down, Notepad++ prevents shut down and requires that I save all my open (and unsaved) files. What settings do I have to change to go back to the way things were?

(The workaround I now use is to first "manually" close Notepad++, before shutting down Windows. But I'd like to skip that step and go back to how things were before.)

(From the F1 page, I'm using "Notepad++ v8.4.7 (64-bit)" "Build time: Nov 1 2022 - 23:31:11".)

---

I already have these settings (but the above problem remains):

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are aware of this inconsistent behavior. It will be [fixed in the next version. For now you can roll back to the latest stable version without this "feature" v8.4.6](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23802/prompt-for-save-if-npp-open-when-win-shutdown/18?_=1671081931550&lang=en-US)

Comment: @MC10: Thanks for that info. I guess I'll just wait for the next version

Comment: Using the Notepad++ menu *Plugins > Plugins Admin tool*, you may install the Auto Save plugin and set it to save everything whenever Notepad++ loses focus. This way all your files should be saved. ([link](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21782/faq-desk-periodic-backup-vs-autosave-plugin))

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

go to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\SessionMgr`

Edit the settings.xml file and change

`<automaticSave value="0"/>` to `<automaticSave value="1"/>`

And your done.  That's all folks.

Comment: In my "...\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\" folder, there is no further "SessionMgr" folder; instead, there's only the single file "converter.ini" and no other files/folders. Nor can I find any "settings.xml" file anywhere in "...\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\". What might you suggest I do?

Comment: Do you have notepad++ installed as portable?  If so you will need to go to the install directory.

If not, then open Notepad++ click file, then "Save Session" that should create the session config for you.   If not then I suggest reinstalling Notepad++

Comment: you just need to install the Session Manager plugin. To do this go to "Plugins" -> "Plugins Admin...", then search for "Session Manager" and click on "Install". Once done, you will have the SessionMgr folder and the settings.xml file in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Notepad++ menu *Plugins > Plugins Admin tool*, you may
install the "Auto Save" plugin and set it to save everything whenever
Notepad++ loses the focus.

This way all your files should be saved before the shutdown
requests that Notepad++ should terminate.

Reference : [FAQ Desk: Periodic Backup vs AutoSave Plugin](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21782/faq-desk-periodic-backup-vs-autosave-plugin).